# Central moments of a Bernoulli distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider a discrete random variable distributed as a Bernoulli:
$$
Y=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{with probability } p\\
0 & \text{with probability } 1-p
\end{cases}
$$

The $n$-th central moment is
$$
\mu_n:=(1-p)^np +(0-p)^n(1-p)
$$

**(Question)** In my application I know $p$, meaning that I know $\mu_n$ for any $n$.

$p$ is a function of $A$ unknown parameters that I want to recover.

My idea is proceeding in this way: I write down $\mu_1,...,\mu_{A}$ and I solve for the $A$ unknowns.

Suppose that I know how to solve for the unknown parameters the obtained system of equations (potentially highly non-linear).

I am struggling to understand whether there is a "structural" limit (other than solving a super complicated system) to the number of parameters that I can pin down. In other words, in principle I could have $A=10000$, and, provided that I know how to solve the final system of equations, I could pin down all $10000$ parameters by writing down the first $10000$ central moments. Correct?

Comment: What exactly is your central objective?

Comment: Pinning down the $A$ unknown parameters.

Comment: I do not understand whether my strategy (using the first A central moments to pin down A unknowns) contains an intrinsic limit on the number of unknowns I can pin down, other than the algebraic difficulties of solving a very complicated system of equations.

Comment: Without knowing *anything* about the function, your question is impossible to answer. There are infinitely many functions that can evaluate to $p$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The moments only depend on the unknown parameters through $p$. Thus they don't contain any more information than does $p$. Fitting to the central moments is a complicated waste of time; all you can find out about the unknown parameters you can find out from $p$ (or, if you prefer, from the second and third central moments, which together determine $p$).

Comment: Not only do the second and third central moments determine $p$, but given the second central moment, there are at most two possible values for the third central moment (you may as well just use its sign)